# Advantages of multiple udp sockets

Tags: multithreading, sockets, networking, udp

Hi this question is from a test i had recently :
(code of a server using one thread for read actions and N number of threads to write where N is the number of Writing actions needed to be done right now)

will using multiple UDP sockets (one for each client )over a single one(one for all of them) have any advantages ?

the official answer :
no because the server is using one thread for read/write per client which wont make it more efficient (students who addressed buffer overflow got full points)

my question is - under any circumstances will changing single UDP to many will have an efficiency impact?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Maybe yes, if you are using BSD Systems (OSX, FreeBSD, etc.). BSD System do not behave well when sending a lot of upd packets on the same sockets. If the sending queue of the socket is full, the packets get dropped. So write on udp sockets never blocks on BSD systems. When you use 10.000 UDP Sockets sending to the same address, no packets will be dropped on the sending host. So there is definitely an advantage, since some OSs do crazy queue management.

Comment: If the socket send buffer is full, `sendto()` either blocks or returns -1 with `errno == EWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN.`.

Comment: Not true on some BSD systems, test it before downvoting. You can consider this a bug actually. But this is still true for OSX for instance.

Comment: To be more precise: UDP sockets on bsd systems are usually ALWAYS writable, like file handles, its a real shame.